# Matching text in 1 table column to part of string in another table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to match the text in a column in one table, to part of a string in a column of a second table, if there is a match an image will be output on my webpage. Below is an example

Products

```
ID | Prod_Code | Colours
1    100         Yellow, Orange, Navy
```

Colours

```
ID | Colour | Image Link
1    Yellow   Yellow swatch image
2    Orange   Orange swatch image
```

What I am trying to achieve is that if the products.colours contains the text "yellow" the yellow swatch image will appear on the screen, same for orange etc.

I know that the table should be normalised for best practice but unfortunately this was not designed by me and there are time constraints.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See the similar question: [Nested MySql Select statement with “where in” clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667378/nested-mysql-select-statement-with-where-in-clause/6667524#6667524)

Comment: You can use something like `ON FIND_IN_SET(Colours.colour, Products.Colours)` for the join.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT p.Prod_Code, c.Image_Link 
FROM Products AS p
  INNER JOIN Colours AS c 
  ON p.Colour LIKE '%' + c.Colour + '%' ;
```

Although that might go a bit pear shaped if you have colours like YELLOW, YELLOW2, etc.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get this to work, so i have altered my tables i now have a link table like this

Product Colour table
Prod Num | Colour_ID
1        | 2
1          3

basically each colour_id corresponds to a particularly colour in the "Colours" table, i want to if Product_ID is equal to Product ID in product table, and colour_ID is equal to Colour_ID in colour table, output the colour image stored in the the colour table (i hope this makes sense!)